# Empty tag <script></script> are changing my page behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to paginate some data from my database on a HTML page. To do that, I have in a  tag and I use jquery + ajax code to fetch the json data from an URL. But something strange is happening and I can't explain it even after some researches.

If I have  before my my script to fetch, everything works perfectly but if I remove this useless balises with nothing in it, nothing get fetches. Any ideas why ?

I tried to investigate but I can't really figure it so I'm turning for some help.

My script :

```
<script></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            url: "api/hosts",
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "HID" },
            { "data": "NEIGHBORHOOD_ID" },
            { "data": "RESPONSE_TIME_ID" },
            { "data": "URL" },
            { "data": "NAME" },
            { "data": "SINCE" },
            { "data": "RESPONSE_RATE" },
            { "data": "THUMBNAIL_URL" },
            { "data": "PICTURE_URL" },
        ]
    } );
} );

</script>
```

I don't know why but it might be the order I call the other script so here there are (they are before the call to the empty )

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"</script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"</script>
```

The expected result would be my code to work without the  empty tag.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: looks like you have not closed the start <script tag properly for some of the js files ...`<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" -- NO END bracket</script>`

Comment: The problem was caused by a typo. Voting to close.

Comment: To explain  Bhushan Kawadkar's comment: Because `<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"` is missing the >`, it is the `>` on `</script>` that ends the start tag, this stops `</script>` being an end tag, the next `<script>` is treated as script content (and ignored because there is a `src` and then `</script>` becomes the actual end tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you have an unclosed `script` tag. The `<script></script>` are closing the previsous tag. Check if there are a `<script src="...">` or `<script src="..." />` without `</script>` right before your js.